# how change the size of the foreign key field in django admin?

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a CharField and a ForeignKey:

```
class FullName(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     last_name  = models.ForeignKey(Name, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

in admin.py i am able to resize the "first_name" field to display whatever i want in localhost:8000/admin.

```
class NameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size': '50'})},
    }
```

but i don't khow how to customize the size of the dropdown of the ForeignKey feild.
i be grateful if someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm,TextInput,Select
from django.models import FullName

class FullNameForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model= FullName #Your Model Name
    fields = '__all__'

    

    widgets = {
        'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'size': '50'})),
        'last_name': Select(attrs={'size': '50'}))
    }
```

And in **admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import FullName
from .forms import FullNameForm

class NameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FullNameForm

admin.site.register(FullName, NameAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks, That was very helpful, but i have another question, in the admin.py i'm using the autocomplete_fields for the foreign key , when i use the "Select" widget , the search area for the autocomplete_fields in django admin disappears, what is the solution?